# hashtag use in java

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to use hashtags in java? Does tho hash tag serve any purpose?

Comment: You aren't calling ShuffleDeck method.

Comment: using `java.util.Collections.shuffle(java.util.List)` would make your code simpler.

Comment: Seriously, what @samlewis said. Using a List would give you access to so many useful methods. You could shuffle(List) for starters, but also you could use an enhanced for loop instead of that unnecessarily complex one for printing cards...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (k = 52; k<deck.length; k--){
```

this loop is bad built.

If you start in k = 52, you want to loop until k is 1 (since there is no need to swap the last element with himself). This way, k wont be < than deck.lenght and the body of the loop will never execute.

Change it to

```
for (k = deck.length; k >= 1; k--){
```

Then, when you make this one:

```
for (l = 0; l<k; l++){
```

k will be 0, so this loop will have the same problem, so change it to

```
for (l = 0; l<deck.length; l++){
```

Going a bit further, the Fisher-Yates shuffle swaps each element with one of the remaining elements on the collection, so

```
int index = shuffle.nextInt(k-1);
```

would be more correct

Answer (score 0):

what you want in your for loop is

```
for(k = deck.length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
```

your indexing is off and it never enters the shuffle algorithm ( I didn't check the correctness of it FYI so you might bump into other problems)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you could simplify your `shuffledDeck()` method:

```
public static void shuffledDeck(String[] deck) {

    List<String> shuffledDeck = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(deck));
    Collections.shuffle(shuffledDeck);

    for (String card : shuffledDeck){
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop within `main()` in your posted code builds the deck from the two string arrays and prints it out as it's building it, but after building the deck you are never actually shuffling it.

After your initial for loop you have to call `ShuffledDeck` (which should be called `shuffleDeck` then loop over the array again printing each card.  Basically:

```
for (int i = 0;  i<number.length; i++) {
    // ...building the deck as before...
}

shuffleDeck(deck);

for (int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(deck[i]);
}
```